# Redirect users#edit to /settings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I want the users#edit action to always be displayed as `/settings`.

In my routes I have

```
get "settings" => "users#edit", as: :settings
```

Any link to settings is like this

```
<%= link_to "Settings", settings_path %>
```

But when I visit `example.com/username/edit`, it doesn't redirect.

How can I redirect this to `settings`? And is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining a new route `settings` you are telling Rails to route all GET requests that come to `/settings` to the `users_controller`'s `edit` method. This does not mean that all requests that use that controller should redirect to another route - here you have just defined two separate routes that use the same controller method.

If you don't want to use `user/edit` ever, then I suggest you remove the route. If you currently have something like

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :users
```

Simply change it to

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :users, except: [:edit]
```

And keep using your `settings_path` helper.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to do this instead

get '/username/edit', to: redirect('/settings')

the one you did above is trying to have that url use a method called 
`edit` in `users_controller` with alias of `settings` to be used as `settings_path` in your link somewhere

It is always helpful to look at Rails API for these kinds of questions

Ref: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

Comment: Good answer, but wouldn't it be better to remove the unused route altogether if it's never used?

Comment: that is also true, however, I don't know the exact circumstances of the question so didn't make that assumption.. but if you're not going to be using the route then getting rid of it is the best course of action